# getting a list of usb devices attached on Mac in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, drop-down-menu, usb

I am pretty much new-bie to IOS development.

I would like to get the list of USB devices attached on my Mac using Xcode.

I am working on an IOS app, in which I would like get the list of USB devices in a dropdown menu(if IOS supports that) and once I select the USB device, I would like to perform some action on it.

Is there any framework or a built-in class that would be of any help?

An example will be very much appreciated.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Xcode 4 User Guide > Manage Your Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/080-Manage_Your_Devices/manage_devices.html)

[Xcode 4 User Guide > Build and Run Your App > Create, Edit, and Manage Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/055-Build_and_Run_Your_App/build_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH14-SW1)